# How to change data type in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array obtained from a database that looks like this:

```
array1 = [Hello, Bye];
```

And not as I'd want:

```
array1 = ["Hello", "Bye"];
```

And so the compiler tells me that Hello and Bye are not defined. Is there any way of changing it without the need of changing the method to obtain it? It is a bit complex and I'd prefer editing it in the html file rather than changing the whole system. I've tried with String(array1) but it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: HTML has arrays? This is news to me. Tag your question properly. If you don't even know which language you are using, how should we?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Javascript inside an html document!

Comment: `[Hello, Bye]` is nonsense is virtually all popular serialisation formats. If that's what your server gives you, you need to change your server, because it's outputting garbage.

Comment: I know... but I didn't code the server, just starting from its output. Is there a way to "stringify" an array like that?

Comment: If that data is embedded as is as Javascript literal, then it's already too late to do anything with it. If you get this as string, e.g. `"[Hello, Bye]"`, you could write your own not-quite-JSON parser to handle this correctly; but that's really madness when the server is the thing that requires fixing.

Comment: @jquery_stack The point is that's not an array. It's a string in a custom format. You need to parse it manually.

Comment: First, wrap your variable as string

Comment: How can I set the variable Hello into a string "Hello"?

Comment: @jquery_stack change your array1 = [Hello, Bye]; to array1 = "[Hello, Bye]";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctry, wrap your array variable as string with " or '

```
var string = "[Hello, Bye]";

string = string.replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)|(\s+)/g, '');

var array = string.split(',');

console.log(array);
```